# Create group column based on multiple "ifelse"

Tags: r

I need to create group column - B that corresponds to another column - A

```
DF
A     B
XXL   1
XXL   1
XL    2
L     3
M     4
M     4
S     5
```

I was trying to use multiple `ifelse` statement. But this didnt work as it returned the column of zeros. As well i tried to use vectorized way of `ifelse` which resulted the same way.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can either use `match` or `factor`

```
 DF$B <- with(DF, match(A, unique(A)))
 DF$B
 #[1] 1 1 2 3 4 4 5
```

Or

```
 as.numeric(factor(DF$A, levels = unique(DF$A)))
 #[1] 1 1 2 3 4 4 5
```

Here are some other options as well

```
 cumsum(!duplicated(DF$A))
 #[1] 1 1 2 3 4 4 5
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, B:= .GRP, A]
```